# C#: Приведение рациональной дроби к строке

Tags: c#

Пишу класс для бесконечных чисел с плавающей точкой. Однако, конвертация в строку происходит неправильно. Сам код:

```
public string ToString(int precision) {
    BigInteger remainder;
    BigInteger result = BigInteger.DivRem(numerator, denominator, out remainder);

    if (remainder == 0)
        return result.ToString();

    BigInteger decimals = (numerator * BigInteger.Pow(10, precision)) / denominator;

    if (decimals == 0)
        return result.ToString();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    while (precision-- > 0 && decimals > 0) {
        sb.Append(decimals % 10);
        decimals /= 10;
    }

    return result + "." + new string(sb.ToString().Reverse().ToArray());
}
```

Дело в том, что после точки не дописываются нули, так, при делении 3/34 должно быть 0.0882..., но получается 0.882...
Проблема, очевидно в этой строке:

```
BigInteger decimals = (numerator * BigInteger.Pow(10, precision)) / denominator;
```

Пожалуйста, подскажите как можно узнать сколько нулей должно быть и нормализовать вывод.

Comment: вы же сами умножаете на степень десятки свой результат `BigInteger.Pow(10, precision)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уберите здесь одну проверку, из-за нее не добавляются нужные нули в конце:

```
while (precision-- > 0 /* && decimals > 0 */) {
    sb.Append(decimals % 10);
    decimals /= 10;
}
```